# WordPress: display full post AND excerpts on one page

Tags: wordpress

Is there a way my category archive display both full posts and excerpts?

What I want is the first two or three latest posts display as full content posts, and all the others as excerpts with just title and a read more button. These are displayed on one page. I am currently using a category archive, on the twentyfifteen theme.

I know I can set a page to either display full or just excerpts, but not a combination. Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Just use a counter and a conditional statement. Count the posts, if the count is 3 or less, use `the_content()`, if the count is more than that, use `the_excerpt()` or create and display your read more button

Answer (score -1):

You can get these in your wordpress loop on page or post.

```html
<?php 

$content = get_content($post->ID); //full content of post

$excerpt = substr($content,0,150); //you can limit charaacter like 150

?>
```

Comment: Please reread OP. And why would you want to use `get_content()`. This isn't even a wordpress function.